# How to make nested numpy 'where' behave like nested if statements?

Tags: numpy, where-clause

To compute `b` in the following code, the `elif` statement runs only when the preceding `if` statement returns `False`

My first question is about `c`. Can we tune the 2nd `where` comparison such that it runs only on those elements of `a_abs` on which the 1st `where` comparison is `False`?

Can we do something similar to the 3rd block of code? That is, run the 2nd condition only on those elements of `a` for which the 1st condition is `False`.

The goal is to increase the speed of execution on large arrays.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 0.1, -0.9, -0.7], \
              [-3.0,  0.0,  1.1], \
              [ 0.5,  0.19, 0.95]])
# 1st block
def f1(x):
    x_abs = np.abs(x)
    if   x_abs < 0.2: return 0.0
    elif x_abs > 0.8: return np.sign(x)
    else:                return x
f1_arr = np.frompyfunc(f1, 1, 1)
b = f1_arr(a)

# 2nd block
a_abs = np.abs(a)
c = np.where(a_abs < 0.2, 0.0,        \
    np.where(a_abs > 0.8, np.sign(a), \
                          a))
# 3rd block
a[a_abs < 0.2] = 0.0
a[a_abs > 0.8] = np.sign[a]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [145]: b
Out[145]: 
array([[0.0, -1.0, -0.7],
       [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
       [0.5, 0.0, 1.0]], dtype=object)
```

Same result with 2 `where`:

```
In [146]: a_abs = np.abs(a)
In [147]: temp = np.where(a_abs<0.2, 0, a)
In [148]: temp = np.where(a_abs>0.8, np.sign(a),a)
In [149]: temp
Out[149]: 
array([[ 0.1 , -1.  , -0.7 ],
       [-1.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ],
       [ 0.5 ,  0.19,  1.  ]])
```

A key thing to remember is the `where` **is not an iterator**.  The arguments to `where` are evaluated before being passed to the function.  That's basic Python syntax.

So both `a_abs<0.2` and `a_abs>0.8` are evaluated.  Also `sign` is evaluated on the whole array.

We could construct a condition combining the 2 tests:

```
In [154]: ~(a_abs<0.2)
Out[154]: 
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True]])
In [155]: ~(a_abs<0.2)&(a_abs>0.8)
Out[155]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True]])
```

Though that doesn't add anything since if `a_abs>0.8` it is also `>0.2`:

```
In [156]: temp = np.where(a_abs<0.2, 0, a)
In [157]: np.where(_155, np.sign(temp), temp)
Out[157]: 
array([[ 0. , -1. , -0.7],
       [-1. ,  0. ,  1. ],
       [ 0.5,  0. ,  1. ]])
```

That is still evaluating `np.sign` on all of the array.  `ufunc` do have their own `where`, which does evaluate the function on a selected subset.  Thus [148] could be written as:

```
In [159]: np.sign(temp, where=a_abs>0.8, out=temp)
Out[159]: 
array([[ 0. , -1. , -0.7],
       [-1. ,  0. ,  1. ],
       [ 0.5,  0. ,  1. ]])
```

I don't think it saves time (though I haven't done tests); it's more useful with `divide` or `log` where certain numeric values will raise errors or warnings.

As a general rule, the compiled numpy methods don't do "short-circuiting".  They work best on the whole-array, and we accept the minor time (and memory) penalty in order to gain much more by using compiled methods.  Use tools like `numba` if you want to fine tune performance in an iterative `c` like manner.

Comment: Performance with numba is very similar to what I get with np.where

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your 2nd block be with `a_abs` instead of `a`?

```
# 2nd block
a_abs = np.abs(a)
c = np.where(a_abs < 0.2, 0.0,        \
    np.where(a_abs > 0.8, np.sign(a_abs), \
                          a_abs))
```

Comment: No, it should be with 'a'